# Can a public class with invisible constructor be extended by a class in another package?

Tags: java, java-8, eclipse-cdt

I'm using an external library where I came across a public class that I want to extend. It's only constructor is package-private, thus invisible to me.

```
public class Token implements IToken {
    Token(int kind, Object source, int offset, int endOffset) {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

My subclass would be

```
public class MyToken extends Token {
    ...
}
```

This gets an error:

> Implicit super constructor Token() is undefined for default constructor. Must define an explicit constructor

When I add a constructor:

```
MyToken(int kind, Object source, int offset, int endOffset) {
    super(kind, source, offset, endOffset);
}
```

I get the error message

> The constructor Token(int, Object, int, int) is not visible

Is there any way to extend this class? If not, what is the purpose of declaring it public?

Comment: *If not, what is the purpose of declaring it public?* - It's a concrete class, so the purpose of declaring it public is that it can be used from other packages. You cannot extend it, but you still can create objects from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any subclass needs to be able to access at least one constructor of the base class.

If you want the subclass to live in another package, you have to make the constructor at least `protected`.

As this comes from a third-party library, it looks like they do not want you to subclass `Token`. There is probably an alternative to subclassing for whatever you need to do here.

Not providing a public constructor is a common pattern for when you (the library author) need to control how instances are created (for example to implement singletons, or to enforce use of factory methods).

> If not, what is the purpose of declaring it public?

A public class can be *used* from anywhere, i.e. you can call methods on an instance that you are given (even if you cannot make new instances yourself).

Comment: he might be able to create instances. There might be a Factory in there somewhere

Comment: @Stultuske: Yes, you can call a Factory to create instances for you. But you cannot do it directly, and the factory - which is provided by the library as well - can control how exactly this happens (for example to prevent invalid states).

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of a *public* class with a restricted constructor can be to leave the construction to a friend class, or a static factory (create) method.

This factory pattern might be the case here. Then you can use:

```
public class MyToken implements IToken {
    private Token delegate;

    public MyToken(int kind, Object source, int offset, int endOffset) {
        // Factory usage:
        delegate = Token.create().withKind(kind).withSource(source)...;
    }

    public int getKind() {
        return delegate.getKind();
    }

    ...
```

Otherwise you could create in *the same package* as `Token` a (base) class with a `public` constructor. **With modular java > 8 this trick will no longer be permitted.**

My personal guess is that `Token` will be created by some `Parser`/`Scanner` class in the same package. Actually even a child class of Token might be returned, as it then can be a nested internal class wich can access fields of the Parser container, like `line` as String, `filePath`.

Creating your own IToken implementation might be the best implementation.

Comment: That'S right. But I don't like the way the Scanner creates those tokens.

Comment: We need to see more code and how `MyToken` will be used, but it is probably best not to subclass at all. It is usually best to let the parser construct its AST/whatever and then work on top of that (instead of mixing any extra business logic into the tokens created by the parser).

Comment: @Sadik: Why don't you like the way the Scanner creates the token (and it is really a problem)?

Comment: @Thilo For my application, the tokens aren't created correctly. For example I need the parser to handle a token "@func", but the Scanner creates two Tokens "@" and "func". I guess I could either fork the Scanner and create Tokens the way I want or I need a post-processing step after the tokenization but before parsing.

Comment: @Sadik I see. Yes, you need a different scanner then, or some post-processing. If the scanner cannot be configured to match your needs, it is probably better to find another one. Maybe open another question about the specific parsing problem with this specific library. Someone with more domain knowledge might chime in.

Answer (score 1):

**No**. It is impossible without changing of `Token` class.

Some libraries can amend class in run-time, but I strongly discourage you from going this way.

Answer (score 1):

You're allowed to use Tokens, but not to create them. For example, this construction would mean you could probably use something like the below in your program:

```
List<Token> tokens = stream.getTokens();
```

So basically the library will create the tokens, and you can work with them but not extend or create any of your own.

Comment: who says he's not able to create them?

Comment: @Stultuske: If you do not have a visible constructur, you cannot create instances. You can only get them from other library methods that do have access to the internal constructors.

Comment: @Stultuske: The package private constructor says that... :-) If you're suggesting a factory, then it's still the factory creating regular Token classes, probably not offering the functionality the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Your point is valid around making class `public` with `protected` constructor but you could try composition to achieve desired functionality where `MyToken` class contains reference of `Token` class. This way, we would be following `Composition over Inheritance` principle as well.